# End kernel panic: vfs: Vista unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (2, 0) HELP!

Tags: kernel, windows-vista

Newbie 
Downloaded torrent.  Used UUI. Placed Ubuntu on appropriately formated disk. I get this message at boot...

0.536889] kernel offset :disabled 
0.563918] - - - [ end kernel panic - not syncing:vfs:unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (2,0)

I saved Ubuntu in D drive, not C because UUI said that it couldn't due to system 32 folders...  I figure whatever fine... Since I knew my system backup is on external I: drive. My goal was to figure out how to have it ask me which I'd like to boot at start up. So it's in D drive... Nothing else significant is on D drive. I can't get into my computer AT ALL... And idk what I'm doing. I'm an online student I'm freaking out please help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today for the first time, but with unknown-block(0,0).  Just prior to this error I got an error "attempt to read or write outside disk hd0".

The last time I rebooted it there was another error involving disk access which caused the boot process to drop down to the (initramfs) prompt.  That seemed to have been resolved by executing the recommended fsck and accepting all of the fixes it recommended.

All of this trouble started after upgrading the system to 16.04 LTS.

Probably relevant in all this is I'm running zfs mirroring two 3TB hard drives housing the /home content.  However, / is on its own drive along with the boot partition.

I've been running with this disk set up for several months without any disk errors until the upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

I was able to use my system again by falling back from 4.4.0-22, to kernel version 4.4.0-21 via the Grub 2 advanced menu option.  It then fell down to (intramfs) prompting me to do the fsck fixes again, which I did.  Upon reboot after fixes I had to, again, fall down to Grub 2's advanced menu option and fall back to 4.4.0-21.  If I tried to boot into the most recent update of the kernel (4.4.0-22) it gave me the "attempt to read or write outside disk hd0" again.

I was still having difficulty with apt, but that went away when I disabled Google's chrome repo.

I was then able to run the software update successfully.  Interestingly, it reinstalled the 4.4.0-22 kernel and demanded a restart.

After the restart the system came back up successfully.  But now I can't run any web browsers.  Firefox exits silently and chrome core dumps.

Comment: None of this helps me, I'm sorry.

Comment: All of that was way over my head and your issue  started off different from the get go so idk how it's relevant.  Please if someone can help my situation I'd be so greatful